# How do I ad Active Directory Schema to a MMC?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I have a Windows 2008 Small Business Server I wish to retire. Currently it holds the FSMO roles. When I go to add the Active Directory Schema snap-in to a MMC, so that I can transfer it to a new Windows 2012 server domain controller, it is not available in the list of "Available Snap-ins". Please note that I have run "regsvr32 schmmgmt.dll" from an elevated command prompt prior to starting the MMC.

How do I add the Active Directory Schema to the MMC?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but alternatively, you might try using ntdsutil.exe to transfer the role: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/255504

Comment: Did you run `regsvr32 schmmgmt.dll` from an elevated command prompt? Did you get a success message when registering the dll?

Comment: Using  ntdsutil.exe per the MS support document worked. Thank you.